# How to change version number printed in apps and features window?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, version

I am developing a C#/.Net application with Visual Studio. See the version indicated in the image below. How can I edit the version information shown in the image? I tried changing AssmeblyInfo, AssemblyInformationalInfo values but those have no impact on the version. [image]

Comment: In Project properties window (Project -> YourProjectName Properties), under Publish, there is a Publish Version section.  Does changing that change the displayed version?

Comment: How are you building your installer?

Comment: with FinalBuilder product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, first comment is correct.

You could try right-click project Properties->find Publish Option->change Publish Version.

[image]

After you published the project and installed it, you will see the following version number in App Features.

[image]

Comment: thanks, i  will try this today and if it is the answer i will accept your answer.